# Некорректное отображение экрана при подключении по RDP

Tags: ubuntu, rdp, vnc

Пытался настроить RDP соединение. Подключение прошло удачно, но вместо экрана появилось зелёное окно, которое после переделалось в серое.

Соединение ubuntu-ubuntu.

Установка была, как [здесь](http://ashep.org/2010/rdp-server-v-linux/).

Comment: rdp - это обязательное условие? линуксам ближе vnc, про проблемы с ним никогда не слышал, и если есть возможность, я бы соскочил на него.

Comment: я как то и через vnc пробовал результат похож. Тем более что rdp на сколько мне известно более производительный. у меня канал иногда очень тормозит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на основании множества источников по поводу «rdp grey screen» и «vnc grey screen» ([1](https://askubuntu.com/q/449785/416190), [2](https://askubuntu.com/q/464389/416190), [3](https://askubuntu.com/q/569600/416190), [4](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04)) можно придти к выводам:

- дефолтно используемое в дистрибутиве *ubuntu* окружение рабочего стола (*desktop environment*, сокращённо *de*) *unity* невозможно отобразить ни с помощью *rdp*, ни с помощью *vnc*.
- скорее всего, заработает (возможно, в обоих случаях, или, по крайней мере, в случае *vnc*) *de* под названием *xfce*. которое можно установить из пакета *xfce4*.

---

подробная инструкция по настройке *vnc* для использования *xfce* приведена по [последней](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04) из упомянутых ссылок. кратко:

помимо установки пакетов, пароля, надо будет создать файл `~/.vnc/xstartup` (и сделать его исполняемым) примерно такого содержания:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```